# How to replace ID numbers with names after exporting from Google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, powerquery, google-sheets-macros

I am currently working on a project for an organization to allow staff members to fill out timesheets online. I am currently using google sheets to do this and it works fine. The problem is that the organization can not store personal information outside of Canada, and after doing research I determined that Google drive does not store the information in Canada. The timesheets need to have employees name and signature on them. This cannot be stored on Google drive but must be put onto the file before printing.

This means that there are a couple different options that came to my mind:

1. Have the ability to use the Google sheets/Google drive API but have the data stored in Canada somehow
2. Use a number instead of the employee's name, and when the files need to be printed, they will be exported as an excel workbook from Google sheets, and the column with the number will be replaced with the employee's actual name automatically (this would be simple if there were only a few employees & it could be done manually, but there are almost 200 employees)

I have tried finding a solution to store the data within Canada. Google cloud seems to be the only way to do this through Google, however, Google cloud has no Google sheets/drive API. I have looked at many different employee timesheet softwares, none of them meet the needs. I have tried to find a solution and came across Powerquery, however, I don't think that it will work for what I am trying to do.

The code that must be updated is very simple. It is just changing one column from each different workbook which contains a number that corresponds with each employee to their actual name. The numbers are obviously different in every workbook, however, the column and row are the exact same.

For example,

- "1234" needs to be changed to "John Cena" in workbook 1234.xlsx
- "1235" needs to be changed to "Margeret Carmex" in workbook 1235.xlsx
- "1236" needs to be changed to "Jossi Wells" in workbook 1236.xlsx

All of the numbers are in column A1 but in their own separate workbooks.
All of the workbooks will be in the same folder after being exported from Google drive.

The expected result is to have column A1 on every single workbook be changed from a number to the name which corresponds to that number.

If anyone has any advice on how to accomplish this using Google sheets, Excel, a macro, or any desktop application please let me know. An option for storing the information within Canada using Google sheets would be ideal.

I am open to any solutions that are not any of the ones that came to my mind as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!D2:E, 2, 1), ))
```

[image]